# Divide the specific element of a list of lists by one number?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have the below list and I want to divide only the third element of the items by 48:

```
  mlst: [(3, 4, 3), (20, 20, 4), (5, 30, 26)]
```

So my expected results should be:

```
 mexlst: [(3, 4, 0.062), (20, 20, 0.083), (5, 30, 0.54)]
```

Comment: Great explanation - what have you tried so far?

Comment: `mexlst = [(x, y, z/48) for (x, y, z) in mlst]` using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: This works very well. Tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using list comprehension:

EDIT: Suggested tuple unpacking from comments

```py
mexlst = [(a, b, c / 48) for (a, b, c) in mlst]
```

This is creating a new tuple for each tuple in your `mlst` with the third element divided by 48.

Alternatively, you can do this with numpy very easily and it will be more performant for large data:

```py
import numpy as np

marray = np.array(mlst) # create Nx3 array
marray[:, 2] /= 48 # divide third column by 48
```

Comment: to me this seems more complicated than necessary. the one-liner in my comment above seems more readable

Comment: You don't need to convert everything to lists and back to tuples. You can add up tuples the same way. Also a better way would be to unpack tuple in you list comprehension (`for (a, b, c) in mlst`).

Comment: Included in my answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To do this efficiently, you can transform your list into an np.array and then extract the third column to divide it by 48:

```
    import numpy as np
    arr = np.array([(3, 4, 3), (20, 20, 4), (5, 30, 26)], dtype=float)
    arr[:, 2] = arr[:, 2]/48
```

Comment: This also works. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use a list comprehension that breaks the original list items into their three component parts, then spits them out but with the third item in each sub-list being divided by 48.

```
mlst = [(3, 4, 3), (20, 20, 4), (5, 30, 26)]

[(a,b,c / 48) for a,b,c in mlst]

# [(3, 4, 0.0625), (20, 20, 0.08333333333333333), 
#    (5, 30, 0.5416666666666666)]
```